# how to evaluate the condition?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

One of row will have the data as     30 > 50, or      170 > 40 etc

How to evalute this varchar column data to find what it represents true or false.
SQL Server 2008 R2 and above.

Comment: Are you saying you have a varchar column with values like '30 > 50' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **MUST** keep your data in this (painful) form, then your best bet will probably be to parse the string into it's individual parts.  Something like the following steps:

1. Parse string into operand1, operator, operand2
2. Cast operand1 and operand2 to int
3. Probably go into some painful case statement to apply the correct operator based on what you parsed out

I would personally recommend finding a way to calculate this before you insert into the database.  What you are storing and what you need are very far apart right now.